# React native fetch web platform Spring boot Set-Cookie not set

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, expo, fetch, setcookie

I have read a lot of SO articles around this and tried a lot of solutions but still can't get to work around this. This is my Spring boot code:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:19006");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Cookie");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

At some other point in code:

```
private HttpSession session() {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
}

session().setAttribute("CURRENT_USER", user);

int useridSession = ((User)session().getAttribute("CURRENT_USER")).getId();
```

When I test the flow from Postman it works well. I see
Set-Cookie : JSESSIONID=9B10D7862C0D240C5E1A0BF082E6196B; Path=/fmbApi; HttpOnly

But in Chrome opened when I press w on react native expo terminal (which opens http://localhost:19006/) I don't see the Set-Cookie header coming back.

My fetch code:

```
const integrate = async (method, url, headers, body) => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: method,
      credentials: 'include'
    }

    if(headers!=null) {
      requestOptions.headers = headers
    }

    if(body!=null) {
      requestOptions.body = body
    }

    console.log('Executing '+ method + ' ' + url)
    let resp
    try {
        resp = await fetch(url, requestOptions)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('There was an error', error);
      }
      const response = await resp.json();
      console.log('response ',resp.headers.get("Set-Cookie"))
      resp.headers.forEach(console.log);
      return response;

}
```

What am I missing?

**Update**: I added

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=false 
server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/
```

So the cookie in Postman looks like this:

```
JSESSIONID=496A19C9C073F0C95A44666A29BAD9CD; Path=/
```

No luck yet.